# Cast Iron Valve/Square Wrench?

Tags: tools, valve, cast-iron, square-nut

Found this in my grandfather’s garage. Any idea what it is/used for? Handle embossed with “KEEP UPRIGHT.” Square hole approximately 15/16".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label reading "KEEP UPRIGHT" implies that it's not a tool, but part of a valve or other mechanical component. Quarter-turn ball valves have similar handles.

My guess is that the valve was required to be installed vertically for proper operation and safety, or that the handle was supposed to be kept at the top so sediment was less likely to compromise the stem seal.

Answer (score 2):

Acetylene tanks use square head valves of this sort. The "keep upright" portion would apply to the tank, rather than the wrench, as the fuel is dissolved in a matrix (sponge-like) of acetone. Having a non-vertical tank would generate liquid rather than gas from the valve.